# Splitting big reducer into smaller reducers

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a feature reducer (slice reducer) called animals. I want to split these reducers to mammals, birds, fishes etc. This part is easy as I can simply use the `ActionReducerMap`.

Now let's say the mammals' reducer's state is huge and I want to split it to several smaller reducers i.e cat's family, dog's family etc. the ActionReducerMap is not returning a reducer and is not nestable. I tried searching the web for solution or example but I couldn't find. My question, in short, is how to make multi-level nested reducers.

```
export interface AnimalsState{
  mammals: fromMammals.mammalsState;
  birds: fromBirds.birdsState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AnimalsState> = {
  mammals: fromMammals.reducer,
  birds: fromBirds.reducer
};
```

I want to split mammals reducer into smaller reducers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can you can compose a new reducer using the [**combineReducers**](https://ngrx.io/api/store/combineReducers) function from `@ngrx/store`, this will allow you to combine your `dogs` and `cats` reducers for the `mammals` state.

I made a quick example of how to use it on [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aki6m7).

The example of the `combineReducers` function can be found in [`app/store/mammals/mammals.reducer.ts`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aki6m7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Fmammals%2Fmammals.reducer.ts):

```
import { combineReducers } from '@ngrx/store';

import { catsStoreName, catsReducer, CatsState } from '../cats';
import { dogsStoreName, dogsReducer, DogsState } from '../dogs';


export type MammalsState = {
  [catsStoreName]: CatsState,
  [dogsStoreName]: DogsState,
}

export const mammalsReducer = combineReducers<MammalsState>({
  [catsStoreName]: catsReducer,
  [dogsStoreName]: dogsReducer,
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
can I ask you what is the meaning of brackets in [catsStoreName]: catsReducer,

Comment: It's a computed/dynamic property name, for example, the value of the `catsStoreName` variable. I used it to not write the store name over and over again.

Comment: I got the following error if I use square brackets: A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.